# Using sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities to show on dependencies that are views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, dependencies

I use the following query to find dependencies on a view

```
    SELECT referenced_entity_name,*  FROM 
sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.WEB_ANALYSER', 'OBJECT')
```

This returns tables and views used in the View.  I want the above query to only return dependencies that are views

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select referenced_entity_name, re.*
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.WEB_ANALYSER', 'OBJECT') as re
  inner join sys.views as sv
    on sv.name = re.referenced_entity_name
```